# How to access property from CCLayer?

Tags: objective-c, properties, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I am adding a layer to my scene and I want to check when it is fully loaded by setting a boolean after my initialization called `doneInitializing` to `YES`. But i need to access it somehow... How do I do that ?

**LoadingScreen.h**

```
@interface LoadingScreen : CCLayerColor{
    CCLayer *hWL;
}
```

**LoadingScreen.m**

```
hWL = [HelloWorldLayer node];

[self addChild:hWL];

if(hWL.doneInitializing == YES){ // that is where I get stuck
//do something

}
```

I can't access the variable `doneInitializing`... WHY ?

**HelloWorldLayer.h**

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer
{   
    BOOL doneInitializing;
}



@property (nonatomic,readwrite) BOOL doneInitializing;
```

**HelloWorldLayer.m**

```
@synthesize doneInitializing;
```

Is there a better approach to achieve this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this part:

```
@interface LoadingScreen : CCLayerColor{
    CCLayer *hWL;
}
```

To this:

```
@interface LoadingScreen : CCLayerColor{
    HelloWorldLayer *hWL;
}
```

OR use this line instead:

```
if(((HelloWorldLayer *)hWL).doneInitializing == YES){
```

Compiler and the runtime needs to know you are getting a property of the `HelloWorldLayer` instead of the `CCLayer`. Although you are assigning `hWL = [HelloWorldLayer node]`, `hWL` has been declared to be a plain `CCLayer` and the line with `hWL.doneInitializing` gets into trouble because as far as the runtime knows, a `CCLayer` does not have a property named `doneInitializing`. You need to tell the runtime "dude, hWL is a HelloWorldLayer" by declaring `hWL` as `HelloWorldLayer` or casting it to that class.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :-) I couldn't have thought about that, but it is clear and obvious, thanks.